# iOS Autolayout storyboard ScrollView - button bottom of the scrollview is unable to clickable

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

Using Storyboard, in `UIViewController` using `UIScrollView`, UIView as content view

Scrollview Constraints - top, bottom, left, right
UIView as contentview constraints - top, bottom, left, right, equal width height to ViewController's View.

I am using these constraints, can anyone please help me out why button is not calling?

Comment: Most likely the button is below the frame of the content view, so it is unable to be clicked on

Comment: i set content size for scrollview as 320,1000 it is scrolling but it is not clickable. i set background color of Contentview but the color is upto 320 568. May i know  how to change content size

Comment: setting the content size just sets the scrollable area, you need to set the height of the Contentview to be 1000 also so that everything in the scrollable area will be clickable

Comment: may i know how to set the contentview height in storyboard

Comment: you cannot do that in storyboard.  You need to remove the auto layout constraints of your UIView inside the scrollview and set its frame programmatically according to the height of the content you want inside the scrollview

Comment: So Can you please post your answer,

Comment: You can do that from storyboard too. Just add the button in last , I mean open left panel of the storyboard and drag the view containing the button to the last in your case after scroll view. Can you please add a screenshot of the storyboard with left panel opened with clicked dropdown of your view??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just now found the answer with removing any autolayout constraints, for content view we have to set constraints like below:

- Top, bottom, left, right
- Align CenterX - here we have to set the content view height then for that constraint we have to set constant as scrollview content size height

Answer (score 0):

The button is not clickable because it is below the frame of the content view.  You need to remove all auto layout constraints from your content view (the UIView inside the scrollview).

Then you can add all the objects that you need to add to the content view and set the height of the content view according to the height of the content.

So lets say that you calculated a height of 1000 for the content of the objects in the scroll view.  You would then need to set the frame of the content view like this:

```
contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,scrollView.frame.size.width, 1000);
```

And don't forget to set the contentSize for the scrollview so that the scrollview knows how much room it needs to scroll.